# Android Emulator says can't play this video for external storage

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to play one video in external storage.

GenelFragment:

```
public class GenelFragment  extends Fragment {

private MediaController mediaController;
private VideoView mgenel;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    View content = view.findViewById(R.id.content);

    VideoView mgenel =(VideoView)getView().findViewById(R.id.Genelvid);

    //Creating MediaController
    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(getActivity());
    mediaController.setAnchorView(mgenel);

    //specify the location of media file
    Uri uri=Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/videos/genel1.mp4");

    //Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView
    mgenel.setMediaController(mediaController);
    mgenel.setVideoURI(uri);
    mgenel.requestFocus();
    mgenel.start();


}

private void setContentView(int fragment_genel) {

}
```

and fragment_genel.xml:

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/Genelvid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="700dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="700dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,OnClick" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

but, when debug emulator, it say can't play this video.what  missed above code.Any suggestion?

Comment: What version of Android is the emulator running on? (its its Q, try a P emulator to start you off)

Comment: The same problem also

Comment: Sorry I haven't heard of that version

Comment: I try many devices,  it is the same

Comment: Have you verified the video file works & that the location is correct? Try this to verify your uri is correct and your video file is playable on Android: `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
startActivity(intent);`

Comment: I will try thx so much